# MappedListIterable<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Weather>'

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have three classes that I am using as models for parsing JSON from an API call. The classes are given below:

```
class MainWeatherInfo {
  double temp;
  double feelsLike;
  double tempMin;
  double tempMax;
  int pressure;
  int humidity;

  MainWeatherInfo(this.temp, this.feelsLike, this.tempMin, this.tempMax,
      this.pressure, this.humidity);

  factory MainWeatherInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return MainWeatherInfo(json['temp'], json['feels_like'], json['temp_min'],
        json['temp_max'], json['pressure'], json['humidity']);
  }
}

class Weather {
  int id;
  String main;
  String description;
  String icon;

  Weather(this.id, this.main, this.description, this.icon);

  factory Weather.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Weather(json['id'], json['main'], json['description'], json['icon']);
  }
}

class WeatherData {
  List<Weather> weather;
  MainWeatherInfo main;

  WeatherData(this.weather, this.main);

  factory WeatherData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    List<Weather> weatherList = json['weather'].map((weather) => Weather.fromJson(weather));
    return WeatherData(weatherList, MainWeatherInfo.fromJson(json['main']));
  }
}
```

But when I start parsing, I get the error saying:
`_TypeError (type 'MappedListIterable<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Weather>')` at the following line:

`List<Weather> weatherList = json['weather'].map((weather) => Weather.fromJson(weather));` in the `factory` constructor of `WeatherData`.

The API response that I get looks something like this and I'm trying to decode `weather` and `main` from the JSON:

```
{
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": 803,
            "main": "Clouds",
            "description": "broken clouds",
            "icon": "04d"
        }
    ],
    "main": {
        "temp": 24.12,
        "feels_like": 24.39,
        "temp_min": 24.12,
        "temp_max": 24.12,
        "pressure": 1012,
        "humidity": 69
    }
}
```

Could anyone help me out in finding where the problem is? Thank you!

The code works fine if I make the `factory` constructor of `WeatherData` look like this:

```
factory WeatherData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    List<Weather> weatherList = [];
    for (var weather in json['weather']) {
      weatherList.add(Weather.fromJson(weather));
    }
    return WeatherData(weatherList, MainWeatherInfo.fromJson(json['main']), json['name']);
  }
```

Comment: Did you try adding `toList()` call at the end of the map function: `json['weather'].map((weather) => Weather.fromJson(weather)).toList()`

Comment: I tried doing that too. But I got another error message saying type ```'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Weather>'```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.map()` returns a `MappedListIterable` and you need to call `.toList()` at the end to convert it into a `List`.

Change the code to this:

```dart
List<Weather> weatherList = json['weather'].map<Weather>((weather) => Weather.fromJson(weather)).toList();
```

Comment: I tried doing that too. But I got another error message saying ```type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Weather>'```.

Comment: @SagunRajLage add a type parameter to `.map()`. Check updated answer